# Add class when element hits top of page AND remove class when element reaches bottom of parent

Tags: jquery, scroll, offset, scrolltop, sticky

What I am trying to achieve:

- When the top of an image reaches the top of window (by scrolling), a class "sticky" is added to the element
- When that image that is now sticky reaches the bottom of its container, the class is removed and the element stays at that last bottom position
- When a user moves back up, the same process happens, only starting from the bottom, going to the top.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GDhXa/)**.

**Relevant jQuery**:

```
$(".entry-thumbnail").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        p = $this.parent(),
        scrollT = $this.scrollTop(),
        scrollW = $(window).scrollTop(),
        scrollPT = p.scrollTop() + p.outerHeight();

    if (!$this.hasClass("sticky")) {
        console.log("Tada!");
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if (scrollT <= scrollW) {
                $this.addClass("sticky");
            }
        });
    }
    else {
       $(window).scroll(function () {
            if (scrollT + $this.outerHeight() >= scrollPT) {
                $this.removeClass("sticky");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Problems that I encounter:

- Class is added to all elements
- Elements position (left/right) changes when adding the class
- Class doesn't get removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a different approach to your problem. I calculate the absolute height required inside the `window.scroll` event handler and then set the height to the appropriate article based on the scroll height.

<s>Check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/eh3sT/ and let me know if it works for you.</s>

**Edit:** You did fix most part of the issue yourself. Thanks :)

I don't think there is much to optimize, but I just modified a little to improve the readability. Check the full demo at http://jsfiddle.net/eh3sT/3/embedded/result/

**Full Code:**

```
var etPos = []
var $articles = $("article");
$articles.each(function () {
    var tPos = $(this).offset();
    etPos.push([tPos.top, tPos.top + $(this).height(), $(this).find('.entry-thumbnail').height()]);
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).scrollTop();
    var cssProp = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < etPos.length; i++) {
        var $atricle = $articles.eq(i);
        if (scrollHeight >= (etPos[i][0]) && scrollHeight <= (etPos[i][1] - etPos[i][2] - 20)) {
            cssProp.top = scrollHeight - etPos[i][0] + 10;
            cssProp.bottome = "auto";
        } else if (scrollHeight > (etPos[i][1] - etPos[i][2] - 20) && $atricle.height() > ($atricle.find('.entry-thumbnail').height() + 10)) {
            /*
            Remove the second condition if the article height is always > respective thumbnail + 10. we don't want set bottom 10, if the thumbnail has no space to scroll.
            */
             cssProp.top = "auto";
             cssProp.bottom = 10;
        }else {
            cssProp.top = 10;
            cssProp.bottom = "auto";
        }
        $atricle.find('.entry-thumbnail').css(cssProp);
    }
});
```

Notes: Added `article` class to all article tags.

Comment: This is a very good start! Works quite good, but there is one mistake that isn't quite noticeable because of the overflow: hidden on the article. You move the thumbnail below the article, so you chould add something to the first if statement. See my edit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eh3sT/1/). Another thing that doesn't work quite well is that I'd like the thumbnail to stick at its last bottom position when you scroll further and that when you move back up, the image starts from that bottom position again. I hope that that's clear?

Comment: I found it out, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eh3sT/2/) it is. Maybe you can optimise it a bit? I don't know. Anyway, make sure to edit your post accordingly and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @BramVanroy You did fix most part of the issue yourself. Thanks :) I have updated my answer. You can checkout the full screen demo http://jsfiddle.net/eh3sT/3/embedded/result/